# How to write xml code (using R xml package) with special characters

Tags: r, xml, special-characters

I am trying to write some xml files that a specific program needs and am having issues writing 'special characters' in some of the text and thus the program is throwing errors.

**How can I write special characters (specifically '>') into attributes of a tag?**

```
library(XML) 

xml <- xmlTree()
  xml$addTag("events", close=FALSE, attrs = c(PackageMinimumVersionRequired="1.3") )  
  
  # '>' is a special character that gets rewritten as '&gt;'
    xml$addTag("schedule", close=TRUE, 
                attrs = c(time = paste("2000-01-01/1 -> +6-0-0", sep='') ) )
xml$addTag('party', close=FALSE, attrs = c(number='1')) #just putting this in to show I have other nodes
xml$closeTag() # close party 
xml$closeTag() # close events
    
saveXML(xml, file = "testfile.xml", encoding = "UTF-8" )
```

the 'time' attribute gets written as: time="2000-01-01/1 **- &gt**; +6-0-0"

I believe something along these lines should be used, but haven't been able to figure out a fix...

```
xmlCDataNode()
# or 
xml$addCData
```

**secondary question - How can I indent to a new line for each tag?**
The xml header has its own line, but otherwise all tags are getting stacked horizontally in the same line. I'd like each new tag to go to a new line (I'm using notepad++ or other editor to see code).

Comment: Please put the secondary question in a separate question. StackOverflow is designed that way: if there were two answers to two different questions, you wouldn't be able to accept them both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was asked to address this since I am the author of the XML package.
As Michael says, if the attribute was

```
time = "2000-01-01/1 -> +6-0-0"
```

that would be malformed XML although xmlParse() and libxml2 will parse it correctly and convert the > to  the &gt; sequence of characters.

Interestingly, the > character is not converted to &gt; when we create the attribute:

```
z = newXMLNode("bob", attrs = c(a = "x > y"))
xmlGetAttr(z, "a")
[1] "x > y"
```

The conversion happens in the call to saveXML(). So, in principle, you could avoid saveXML() and write R code to traverse the tree and generate the output yourself, handling each attribute the way you want. However, that's the last resort.

As much as I hate using regular expressions to deal with XML, I suggest you post-process the output of saveXML() and, if your content is "uniform", replace all &gt; with >, i.e.,

```
cat(gsub("&gt;", ">", saveXML(xml$value())))

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<events PackageMinimumVersionRequired="1.3">
  <schedule time="2000-01-01/1 -> +6-0-0"/>
  <party number="1"/>
</events>
```

This is relatively simple if you can replace **all** &gt; with >. If you need to replace the &gt; for only a subset of the occurrences in certain contexts, your regular expression will have to be more complex.

Q2 To get nodes on separate lines and indented, use

```
saveXML(xml$value(), "testfile.xml", encoding = "UTF-8")
```

i.e., get the document object by call `xml$value()` and save that.

BTW, my preference is to not use xmlTree() and its collection of functions (e.g. add and close), but rather

```
doc = newXMLDoc()
e = newXMLNode("events", attrs = c(PackageMinimumVersionRequired="1.3") , doc = doc)
newXMLNode("schedule", attrs = c(time = paste("2000-01-01/1 -> +6-0-0", sep='')), parent = e)
```

and you can even chose to drop the `doc` part.

Answer (score 0):

Some characters, notably `<` and `&`, must always be escaped. If your library didn't escape these characters, the output wouldn't be well-formed XML and would be unusable.

Other characters, such as `>`, `"`, and `'`, need to be escaped under particular conditions, and many libraries will escape them unconditionally because that's the easiest thing to do, and once you've put the XML through a parser it makes no difference anyway. If you really want `>` to be unescaped you should be asking yourself why. Is it just for aesthetic reasons? If downstream software relies on it being unescaped, then the downstream software is buggy - and writing XML that can be consumed by buggy clients accounts for an awful lot of StackOverflow traffic, so you've got a problem on your hands.

Comment: I didn't write the downstream software. I just need to work within its confines unfortunately. 
How would I unescape the '>' in my code?

Comment: I can only advise you that XML as a standard offers enormous benefits it you use it properly and none at all if you don't. If everyone follows XML standards, you get the chance to exploit a vast range of commodity software. As soon as someone starts departing from the standards, or insisting on the use of a private subset, you lose all of that.